# Java: is CountDownLatch threadsafe

Tags: java, thread-safety, countdownlatch

In the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for `CountDownLatch` I see something like:

```
public void run() {
      try {
        startSignal.await();
        doWork();
        doneSignal.countDown();
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {} // return;
}
```

Here `startSignal` and `doneSignal` are `CountDownLatch` objects.

The docs don't mention anything about the class being thread-safe or not.

Comment: Define *thread-safe* in this case.

Comment: Thread safely, in this case would be, for example, to ensure that only one thread calls `countDown` at a time. The signature does not say it is synchronized: `public void countDown()`

Comment: `CountDownLatch` guarantees that `await` will block until `countDown()` is called exactly the specified number of times no matter how many threads might call it at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it is designed to be used by multiple threads it would be fair to assume that it **is** thread-safe to most meanings of *thread-safe*.

There is even a *happens-before* commitment (from [your link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)):

> Memory consistency effects: Until the count reaches zero, actions in a thread prior to calling countDown() happen-before actions following a successful return from a corresponding await() in another thread.

With reference to your specific question *What if two threads call countDown at the same time? Wouldn't it just do the count down action only once effectively?* No, two `countDown`s will be actioned every time.

Comment: But shouldn't calling `countDown` itself be synchronized ? What if two threads call `countDown` at the same time? Wouldn't it just do the count down action only once effectively?

Comment: @treecoder you seem to equate "a method is thread-safe" with "a method is synchronized". That's incorrect. There are several ways to make a method thread-safe without making it synchronized. CountDownLatch internally uses non-blocking thread-safe operations. Everything under java.util.concurrent is designed to be used by multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** the class or rather the methods you call on a `CountDownLatch` objects arr **thread-safe**.

In order to make these operations such as `countDown()` `await()` thread-safe, they have not used `synchronize` block or functions. Rather they have used **Compare and Swap** strategy.
Below is the source codes which proves the same

```
sync.releaseShared(1);

public final boolean releaseShared(int arg) {
    if (tryReleaseShared(arg)) {
        doReleaseShared();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

protected boolean tryReleaseShared(int releases) {
        // Decrement count; signal when transition to zero
        for (;;) {
            int c = getState();
            if (c == 0)
                return false;
            int nextc = c-1;
            if (compareAndSetState(c, nextc))
                return nextc == 0;
        }
    }
```

The above code is a part of the total implementation, you can check source codes for other methods like `await()` as well.